# Error during ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, hard-drive

First time Linux user.

I'm trying to get Ubuntu fully installed on an external SSD connected with a USBC cable. I want it to be fully installed, so it can work on any computer. The linux flashed thing is on a USB.
The problem is that during the 'copying files' stage of the installation, I get Errno 5, Input / output error.

The first time I tried, I didn't realise I needed to disable the boot flags on the internal windows HDD. Linux was installed correctly with no errors - I could see the file system - but I couldn't boot from it.

The second time I tried, I disabled the boot flag on the internal hdd. Now when I try to install linux on the external SSD, I get the aforementioned error. I tried again and ran ubiquity no-migration-assistant before trying to install, but I got the same error.

Any thoughts?

Specific information:

- Secure boot is disabled. Fast boot is disabled. The laptop has ahci enabled.
- Version of linux: 22.04 LTS https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
- The computer is an Acer i7-3537u, 2.0ghz, 4GB memory, 500TB HDD, with USB 3.0 and a nvidia geforce grafics card. Windows is installed on the HDD (I do not want to touch this HDD).

Comment: @user535733 the drive is new, and it was able to copy all files across successfully before, as stated above (the first time I did it).

Comment: The upshot is that Err 5 is not usually a *software* problem. The system is merely passing along notice that data cannot be exchanged due to hardware fault.

Comment: @user535733 The disk worked earlier though... Any idea how to fix this without buying a new disk?

Comment: It likely cannot be *fixed* by Ubuntu. You can gather diagnostic information using SMART. You can try a different data cable. You can consult the manufacturer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the USB that had the iso flashed. I replaced the USB and it worked without errors.